# React: map through string and give a command to each iteration. Then calculate the result

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary, state

So I have a challange made for me in React.

The challange is this. Imagine a 2d grid with an x and an y axis. Like so:

```
           (+y)
            ^
            |
            |
 (-x) <-----+-----> (+x)
            |
            |
            v
           (-y)
```

Using 2d vector, (x,y) you can se were in the grid you are located. so (0,0) is straight in the middle

so you start at (0,0) and from there, and any location you move in four different directions. left, right, up or down.

You are given a list of instructions on which direction to move. Each instruction moves you exactly one square in the corresponding direction. These instructions are encoded as a string of ascii characters, where each character corresponds to one instruction:

- `^` move up (north) (y +1)
- `v` move down (south) (y -1)
- `>` move right (east) (x +1)
- `<` move left (west) (x -1)

so ">>>" will move you three possitions to the right. You ending up at (3,0)
and "<<^^<

You have to implement the following two functions that would answer these questions:

1. What is the final location after all instructions are processed?
2. Which is the first location you will visit twice?

Assume that any valid string could be given as input.

The starting code i have made so far, so you understand the problem better: https://repl.it/@jdegrell/map-through-the-grid

feel free to change anything in that tho.

So calculate the final location in itself is easy. Just loop through the array version of the string and increment or decrement x and y depending on the input. like so:

```
var coord = [0,0]

for (var i=0; i < inputData.split("").length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == ">") {
            cord[0]++
        } else if (arr[i] == "<")
        {
            cord[0]--
        } else if (arr[i] == "^")
        {
            cord[1]++
        }
        else if (arr[i] == "v")
        {
            cord[1]--
        }
    }
```

But this becomes a problem when we need to calculate which is the first location is visited twice. for this i need to itirate the loop, and also know previous steps on the grid. So i need to map through insteed. But i'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Anyone wanna help me with a solution, and maybe explain how to use map correctly in this situation.

Thanks.